# Please explain location of end of verse pattern in Ha'azinu

Tags: safrus, haazinu

Parshat Ha'azinu is, for the most, written in 2 side-by-side columns. I noticed the following pattern:

- verses 1-13 end in the left column
- verses 14-38 end in the right column
- verses 39-43 end in the left column

I assume that there is little flexibility for Sofrim when writing Ha'azinu, i.e. certain words must end in each of the columns throughout the song. Is this a correct assumption? If so, is there any significance or meaning to this verse pattern that I mentioned?

Comment: Most of the verses have an even number of poetic phrases. Some have an odd number.

Comment: Without doing a full analysis - IIRC, Shirat Ha'azinu is composed of an opening which is good, a middle that is full of negative verses and ends in the reassurance that G-d will redeem Israel and lead to Vezot Habrachah. Maybe the breaks connect - anyone learnt this? Connection with even/odd or left/right in Kabbalah?

Comment: @DoubleAA Sounds like a good answer. Why not post it as such?